# Change variable at certain time

Tags: php

So I have a $today variable created like this:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
$today = date("H:i:s:T");
```

Is there a way I can have a variable change when the time gets to a certain point every day, without anyone being on the page or does that require a different programming language?  (I'm using XAMPP right now to run this)

```
if($today == "10:50:00:EST"){
    $variable1 = $anotherVariable;
}
```

Comment: For time based operations one would usually use cronjobs. Would this work for your problem? If not, why?

Comment: What do you want to happen once the variable changes?

Comment: @Dragony that may work I'll look into that

Comment: @TimB Nothing really, just change the variable. The time will keep going and the next day at that time it will change the variable again.

Comment: cron is the only way to perform task in php without page request.

Comment: @dev Yeah I see that now. Thanks everyone for your help!

Comment: Why would you want the time to change without anyone being on the page? Just wondering

Comment: If changing the variable doesn't do anything then why change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mis-understand how it works - the script will only run if you have a cron-job or someone access the page. (and a cron job is basically the computer accessing the page at a specific time!)

If you want a variable dependant on time of day simply use a if statement

(pseudo code)

```
if(now() < $time){
    $var = 1;
}else{
    $var = 2;
}
```

This means that anyone who visits the page before $time gets $var1 and after gets $var2

A cron Job is exactly the same as someone loading the page so any code you enter after will still run - make sense?

Comment: Yes! Thank you it all makes sense now!

Answer (score 0):

You would use a `cron job` to accomplish this.  A cron job is a scheduled task that is executed by the system at a specified time/date.

http://www.howtoforge.com/a-short-introduction-to-cron-jobs